# JPA tools creation entity, name class incorrect

Tags: java, mysql, oracle, jpa

When i create entity class from a table of database, often but not always, the name of the class does not have the last letter.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VIEW_APP_GLOBAL_SIGN_CFS")
public class ViewAppGlobalSignCf implements Serializable { ........
}
```

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle as they are two different RDBMS? (although both are owned by Oracle Corp.)

Comment: Why do you have table names with asterisks?

Comment: `**ViewAppGlobalSignCf*`* is not a valid class name.

Comment: Sorry there are no asterisks in the code. 
I corrected.